# IF EXISTS condition

Tags: mysql

I need to do and IF/THEN statement in mysql based on whether a value exists in a column. If it exists, I need to perform an update on the record and if it does not, then an error should be thrown.

I want to check that the siteID actually exists. How can I add an "IF EXISTS" statement?

```
    UPDATE Site SET     siteName = _siteName,
                    siteAddress1 = _siteAddress1,
                    siteAddress2 = _siteAddress2, 
                    siteCity = _siteCity, 
                    siteState = _siteState, 
                    siteZipCode = _siteZipCode,
                    siteCountryCode = _siteCountryCode, 
                    siteCode1 = _siteCode1, 
                    phoneNumber = _phoneNumber, 
                    website = _website
WHERE siteID = _siteID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly discourage people from doing `IF EXISTS THEN UPDATE` because if the value doesn't exist then no action is taken anyway. Additionally, unless your transaction isolation is set correctly, then the record could be added/modified between executing the `EXISTS` portion of the query and the body of the conditional. The only time I can think of when it could potentially be needed is if you need to perform more than one action on existence.

Either way, this is how you would do it:

```
    UPDATE Site 
       SET siteName = _siteName,
           siteAddress1 = _siteAddress1,
           siteAddress2 = _siteAddress2, 
           siteCity = _siteCity, 
           siteState = _siteState, 
           siteZipCode = _siteZipCode,
           siteCountryCode = _siteCountryCode, 
           siteCode1 = _siteCode1, 
           phoneNumber = _phoneNumber, 
           website = _website
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Site WHERE siteID = _siteID);
```

As you just want to raise an error if no action is performed, you could actually check the [ROW_COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) after the update to see if anything was actually done:

```
-- after the update you can call ROW_COUNT() to see how many rows changed
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

If you are creating a procedure, you can use the classic `IF EXISTS` format:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_SITE_IF_EXISTS()
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Site WHERE SiteID = _siteID) THEN
    UPDATE Site SET ...; -- your update statement goes here
  ELSE 
    -- do something else
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You could combine the procedure with the `ROW_COUNT` function to throw the error:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_SITE_IF_EXISTS()
BEGIN
  UPDATE Site SET (...);
  SELECT _rowCount = ROW_COUNT();
  IF (_rowCount = 0) THEN
     -- throw your error...
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you trying to do an `UPSERT` (insert or update depending on if the record exists) then you should also consider using [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO Site (...)
VALUES(...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col = VALUES(_col) -- and so on...
```

For more information check out the documentation for [IF..THEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) and [SUBQUERIES WITH EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Comment: I think `ROW_COUNT` will be zero when the row exists, but none of the columns changed in value.